# converting list into individual separate list

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy.ndarray which is like this:

```
X = array([1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 2., 1., 1.])
```

I tried to convert into lists by doing this:

```
samples = X.reshape(len(X)).tolist()
```

which gave output like this

```
[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0]
```

tried to convert the above into separate lists. did this

```
new_list = [samples[i] for i in range(10)]
```

which gave an output like this again:

```
[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0]
```

im trying to get an output like this:

```
[1.0]
[1.0]
[1.0]
[1.0]
[1.0]
[1.0]
[1.0]
[2.0]
[1.0]
[1.0]
```

can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: Do note that for large lists, reshaping the numpy array and then obtaining a list will be much faster than using a list comprehension

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using list comprehension, [more details](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

**Replace your code:**

```
new_list = [samples[i] for i in range(10)]
```

**To**

```
new_list = [[samples[i]] for i in range(10)]
```

**O/P:**

```
[[1.0], [1.0], [1.0], [1.0], [1.0], [1.0], [1.0], [2.0], [1.0], [1.0]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Add an aditional axis to your numpy array using either `None` or `np.newaxis`, and then use [`ndarray.tolist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html), which will directly give you a nested list:

```
X[:,None].tolist()
# [[1.0], [1.0], [1.0], [1.0], [1.0], [1.0], [1.0], [2.0], [1.0], [1.0]]
```

---

Your approach with [`np.reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) does not work as you're not adding any axis, you'd need:

```
X.reshape(len(X), 1).tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

samples[i] should be in a list:

```
new_list = [[samples[i]] for i in range(10)]
```